# Where does Visual Studio Code store information about enabled extensions per workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has [the option to disable extension globally and enable it only for specific workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_disable-an-extension).

Where is this settings saved? In which file exactly?

Locations where I checked but couldn't find it are:

- [user settings file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations): `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- workspace settings file (e.g., for my single-folder project it is located in `.vscode/settings.json`)
- extensions installation folder: `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`

Where is this setting?

Comment: maybe in one of these locations, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage

Comment: do you maybe know are these storage data stored in some file that I can view? (note: I have no experience with vs code extension development)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visual Studio Code stores that information in:

**Windows**: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\workspaceStorage`

**Linux**: `~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage`

**macOS**: `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage`

Each subdirectory contains three files: `workspace.json`, `state.vscdb`, and `state.vscdb.backup`.

`workspace.json` is a JSON file that contains the URI of the workspace folder. Example:

```json
{
  "folder": "file:///c%3A/Users/josia/MEGA/Projects/Programming%20Languages/Python/JSON%20Serialize"
}
```

`state.vscdb` (and `state.vscdb.backup`) are SQLite3 files that contain the workspace information that you are looking for. They can be opened with an SQLite viewer/editor such as [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Comment: If this is the correct answer, @mlst should have accepted. I came to this thread because I'm looking for an easy way to set the desired extensions for a workspace. It's easy to set Recommended Extensions (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions). The problem is that we need to manually get the list of extensions IDs from each extension. I was looking for a list in JSON format. I'm sure a utility can be created to query the state db files, and save the result in text suitable for copy/paste.

Comment: Also, the relevant fields in the database are `extensionsIdentifiers/disabled` and `extensionsIdentifiers/enabled`.  Note that on Linux, I had to close ALL instances of VSCode (not just the workspace I was editing) in order for edits to those files to be picked up.

Comment: `$HOME/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage` doesn't exist for me, using `code-insiders-1.88.0-1710157206.el8`.