# Where can I find where configuration-like information for VS Code is stored?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, there are several places that store user settings. I am aware of at least

- settings.json
- state.vscdb
- the Settings button on the left panel.

If I am looking for a setting, where should I look for it?

For example, recently I was looking for where Python interpreter was saved. From hindsight, I knew it was saved in state.vscdb file. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153203)

Is there a guideline that tells me how the user settings spread among the places?

Comment: python interpreter is saved in `settings.json`, project settings are saved in `settings.json` (global or project), workspace layout is saved in `state.vscdb` per Workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of there being an official guide on where everything configuration-related is stored. The different storages VS Code has are typically separated in location by purpose and storage type or some other use-case-related thing. It's a little complicated, but such is the nature of things.

For user-level settings, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations. That platform-specific-located `User/` directory is also where user snippets, profiles, keybindings, and a bunch of other cache-related information is stored as well. Information about various types / locations of storage for actual settings (in the official VS Code sense of the word) is kind of implied in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-precedence. There's [profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles), the "default profile"'s settings.json, workspace `.vscode/settings.json`, multi-root workspace `*.code-workspace` files' `"settings"` property.

There's an official doc on what storage features are available to extension authors: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities. See also [How to persist information for a vscode extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51821924/11107541). Technically an extension could put configuration-related things in there, but that'd be pretty unconventional.

For other things:

- [Where do code snippets reside in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69347454/11107541)
- [Where does Visual Studio Code store information about enabled extensions per workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57760451/11107541)
- [Where VS Code stores the list of open files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48014141/11107541)
- [Where does VSCode save the context about open files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71505456/11107541)
- [Where does vscode store the python interpretter setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70405350/11107541)
- [Where does VS Code store its memory of what notifications I've previously requested to not be given again in the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58900482/11107541)

Technically, most conventional user configuration can go anywhere. See also [portable mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) and the `--user-data-dir` commandline argument, which is basically for specifying a non-default `.../User/` directory.